# Michael Hartl's tutorial Chapter 10.2.2, listing 10.26 tests failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

Going through Hartl's tutorial and have searched for an answer, but found none. (There may be answers existing but becuase the chapters have been updated and switched around in the newer editions I can't find them if they exist.)

I am at section 10.2.2. listing 10.26 doing the rails test.

here is the error for my tests:

```
ERROR["test_should_redirect_edit_when_logged_in_as_wrong_user", UsersControllerTest, 1.5802158990409225]
 test_should_redirect_edit_when_logged_in_as_wrong_user#UsersControllerTest (1.58s)
BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash:         BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash: invalid hash
            app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:9:in `create'
            test/test_helper.rb:32:in `log_in_as'
            test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:29:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'

ERROR["test_should_redirect_update_when_logged_in_as_wrong_user", UsersControllerTest, 1.606778411893174]
 test_should_redirect_update_when_logged_in_as_wrong_user#UsersControllerTest (1.61s)
BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash:         BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash: invalid hash
            app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:9:in `create'
            test/test_helper.rb:32:in `log_in_as'
            test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:36:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'

  35/35: [=====================================================] 100% Time: 00:00:01, Time: 00:00:01

Finished in 1.71823s
35 tests, 87 assertions, 0 failures, 2 errors, 0 skips
```

test/fixtures/users.yml

```
michael:
  name: Michael Example
  email: michael@example.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>

archer:
  name: Sterling Archer
  email: duchess@example.gov
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %
```

test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
    @other_user = users(:archer)
  end

  test "should get new" do
    get signup_path
    assert_response :success
  end

 test "should redirect edit when not logged in" do
    get edit_user_path(@user)
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to login_url
  end

  test "should redirect update when not logged in" do
    patch user_path(@user), params: { user: { name: @user.name,
                                              email: @user.email } }
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to login_url
  end

   test "should redirect edit when logged in as wrong user" do
    log_in_as(@other_user)
    get edit_user_path(@user)
    assert flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
  end

  test "should redirect update when logged in as wrong user" do
    log_in_as(@other_user)
    patch user_path(@user), params: { user: { name: @user.name,
                                              email: @user.email } }
    assert flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
  end

end
```

app/controllers/users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

    before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]
    before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
  #  @user = User.new(params[:user])    # Not the final implementation!
    if @user.save
      log_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
      # Handle a successful save.
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    # can take out because already in correct_user     @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    # can take out because already in correct_user @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      # Handle a successful update.
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user

    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end

    # Before filters

    # Confirms a logged-in user.
    def logged_in_user
      unless logged_in?
        flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
        redirect_to login_url
      end
    end

        # Confirms the correct user.
    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless @user == current_user
    end

end
```

Why am I getting 2 failed tests when the book says that all tests should pass? I have looked at the lines the error message mentions ,but I am not sure what is wrong.
Thanks for the help.

EDIT: Sessions controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create

    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)

    if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
    log_in @user
    params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(@user) : forget(@user) 
    redirect_to @user

    else
    flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination' # Not quite right!
    render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    log_out if logged_in?
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a closing angle bracket in the `password_digest` for the "Sterling Archer" test fixture.

```
password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %
```

should be

```
password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
```

Answer (score 0):

look more attentively at line:

```
BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash: invalid hash
            app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:9:in `create'
```

You did not specify the code for this controller, and I can not tell you what might be wrong.

Comment: sorry, yes now edited to include sessions controller, but i still dont understand what is wrong with that line

Comment: @Owen check each file that is specified in the trace, until you find an error.
Next line is: test/test_helper.rb:32:in `log_in_as'

Comment: that's my problem i dont see any errors. all the code is copied from the book.